# How to convert a String into float inside a loop

Tags: java, string, floating-point

I have to convert String into float I am doing it like this :

```
float[] iLongs = new float[mLongs.length];
for(int i = 0; i < iLongs.length ; i++){
    iLongs[i] = Float.valueOf(mLongs[i]).floatValue();
}
```

But it throws numberformat exception

But if I use the same function outside any loop it works.
What to do ?

Comment: Why aren't you using [`Float.parseFloat()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29)? What is the string that causes the `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with loops and everything to do with the values of the Strings in `mLongs`.

Comment: i think u r converting `String Array`  to 'Float Array'

Comment: You should include the code that generates `mLongs` so that we can reproduce the problem.  This will help us get to the heart of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The code looks fine, which leads me to suspect that it's a data issue. You need to verify that every index for mLongs contains a String that is actually valid as a float, how you do that is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative code :**

```
class StringToFloat  {    
  public static void main (String[] args)   {     

    // String s = "hello";    // do this if you want an exception
    String s = "100.00";

    try {
      float f = Float.valueOf(s.trim()).floatValue();
      System.out.println("float f = " + f);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}

// Output :float f = 100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code.
Exception happend because String is not a Float and cannot be parsed. Most common mistake - , instead of .

Answer (score 0):

You are correct syntactically. I think problem is in mLongs. It might contain some alphabetic character.